# How to read the input of a Fortran program in one row (without modifying source code)?

Tags: bash, fortran

How can I perform the following operations?

```
./a.out 1 2
```

instead of using:

```
./a.out
```

'Enter first value:' `(read) 1`

'Enter second value:' `(read) 2`

I wouldn't like to modify the source of my program `a.out` written in Fortran.

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow, be sure to read the help section. If a question solved your problem you can accept it by clicking on a green mark on the left of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Just put a wrapper around your `a.out`. So, save the following as `wrapper`:

```
#!/bin/bash
./a.out<<EOF
$1
$2
EOF
```

Now make that executable with:

```
chmod +x wrapper
```

Then you can run:

```
./wrapper 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I apply a similar command "./a.out<<EOF 1 2 EOF", i.e. your script in one row?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you can do `printf "%s\n%s\n" $1 $2 | ./a.out` in one line.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this! Thank you for your help!